# field annotated with `@value` is not initialized in mongock configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongock

I need to assure data migration using mongock.
The @ChangeUnit class holds the logic for migration. It has a field annotated with `@Value` which is always null, even though I properly initialized in `application.properties`:

```
mongock.migration-scan-package=my.package
login-secret=test
```

Then the `MigrationConfiguration` looks as follows:

```
@ChangeUnit(id = "test", order = "001", author = "test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class InitUsersChangeLog {

  private final MyService service;
  private final MongoTemplate template;

  @Value("${login-secret}")
  private String LOGIN;

  @Execution
  public void initUser() {
    service.create(User.builder().login(LOGIN).build());
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
@EnableMongock
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailServiceApplication {...}
```

My assumption is that this value is not injected properly into the MongockConfiguration bean. I tried to configure the bean manually (without using mongock.migration-scan-package=my.package) in the properties, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mongock currently doesn't support @Value annotation you can try to use `getProperty` method from `Environment` bean. Environment bean can be injected same as other beans using constructor or Lombok annotations.

You want to change this:

```
@Value("your.key.property")
```

to that:

```
private final Environment env;
  
public void method(){
  env.getProperty("your.key.property")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongock currently no supports @value injection via field o method parameter. We will provide that in a future minor release within version 5, but we can't give you dates, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Extending MichalJ's answer, which is absolutely valid. I would like to add that the changeUnits are not retrieved by Mongock via Springboot, they are processed by Mongock independently. So the annotation @Configuration, @Component, etc. won't be taken into account and they could even be damaging.

Related to that, this code won't work, at least not in a near future:

```java
  @Value("${login-secret}")
  private String LOGIN;
```

First, as said, Mongock doesn't support value currently, but the first approach will require the constructor parameter to have that `@Value("${login-secret}")`, not at the field level.